# Switch from the position representation to the momentum representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, fourier-transform, representation-theory

If we use Fourier Transform, we can switch from the position representation to the momentum representation, like the following formula 
[image: use Fourier Transform]

here comes the problem, if we use dirac notation we can see it is the inverse  Fourier Transform we use to switch into the momentum representation
[image: use inverse Fourier Transform]

This is used in one published paper. title:" A finite-dimensional quantum model for the stock market" author:Liviu-Adrian Cotfas, page 7, formula 32

also how can I get the transformation of operator in position and mentum representation via inverse Fourier Transform and Fourier Transform? `\hat{p}=F^{-1}\hat{x}F`
many thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your primary question please

Comment: If you're wondering why the transform and its inverse are identical, its because there is no agreed upon convention - though once you define one, the other is obviously set as well.

Comment: first thanks for your answeing.how about my second question?

Answer (score 2):

No contrast occurs using the dirac notation.

$\phi(p)=\langle p|\Psi\rangle \\ \psi(x)=\langle x|\Psi\rangle$

So $\phi(p)=\langle p|\Psi\rangle=\int dx\langle p|x\rangle \langle x|\Psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int dx\, e^{-ipx/\hbar}\psi(x)$ giving your first equation.

About your second question. In order to transform an operator A from say the position representation to the momentum representation you should transform the matrix elements:

$\langle p_t|A|p_l\rangle = \Sigma_{i,j}\langle p_t|x_i\rangle\langle x_i|A|x_j\rangle \langle x_j|p_l\rangle $

Comment: but what's wrong with my derivation？ I just derive that momentum vector is obtained by inverse Fourier Transform.

Comment: also for the second question, next step in your derivation, you obtain that  \hat{p}=F\hat{x}F^{-1} , just the opposite of mine. really thanks for your answering. @ workaholic